# looping through SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r

I am trying to get area of overlapping polygons by using a combination of gArea, gUnion, and gIntersection in the rgeos package.

For this question, I am using locations of animals provided by adehabitatLT to create home ranges which will be the polygons.

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(rgeos)
data(puechabonsp)
```

Manipulating data to the format I want

```
locs <- puechabonsp$relocs
locs <- as.data.frame(locs)
da <- as.character(locs$Date)
da <- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(locs$Date),"%y%m%d"))
puech <- as.ltraj(xy = locs[,c("X","Y")], date = da, id = locs$Name)
puech2<-ld(puech)
```

Finished manipulation - data is now spatialpointsdataframe

```
pigsp<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=cbind(puech2$x,puech2$x), 
data=data.frame(puech2$id),proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14"))

pigkern<-kernelUD(pigsp) #kernel homeranges

pigvert<-getverticeshr(pigkern,95) #vertice of home ranges (the polygons)

proj4string(pigvert)<-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14") #add projection

uniqueID<-unique(pigvert@data$id) #list of unique animal ids
```

The code below is where I'm stuck. I am trying to get area of overlap for each possible combination of animal IDs.

```
test <-  lapply( combn( uniqueID, 2 ), 2,
              function(x) { 
              SIcomb <- gArea(gIntersection(pigvert@data$id[ x[1] ], 
                pigvert@data$id[ x[2] ]))/
                gArea(gUnion(pigvert@data$id[ x[1] ], pigvert@data$id[ x[2] 
]))
            }  )
```

I suspect I am not doing the lapply correctly but cannot figure it out. Tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not passing an `sp` object to `gUnion()` which is what is causing the issue. I was able to use a `for()` loop with a subset of the original data based on unique names:

```
> uniqueID_combn <- combn(uniqueID, 2)
> for(x in 1:(length(uniqueID_combn)/2)){
+   sp1 <- subset(pigvert, id == uniqueID_combn[1, x])
+   sp2 <- subset(pigvert, id == uniqueID_combn[2, x])
+   print(gArea(gUnion(sp1, sp2)))
+ }
[1] 3337444
[1] 3793138
[1] 3319134
[1] 2462282
[1] 1162276
[1] 2462282
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you. Could you please slightly modify your code to add ID combinations to the output so I know which 2 animals were compared for each gArea?

Comment: I was able to extract gArea for each ID-ID combination with:

Comment: stats[x]<-paste(gArea(gUnion(sp1, sp2)),sp1@data$id,sp2@data$id,sep="-")

Comment: Nice! Yeah if you still wanted to add in ID combinations to the output I would do something like `print(uniqueID_combn[1, x])` or just bind that to a data.frame as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I evaluated the codes by using animals with non-overlapping home ranges (ibex in adehabitatLT). The results produce 7 digit gArea values for individuals with non-overlapping home ranges (Individuals A153 and A289 in the ibex dataset). I would have expected zero values. Thoughts?

Comment: One can insert if(gIntersection) statement to deal with home ranges that do not overlap.